# Getting data out of a completion handler and into a tableView

Tags: swift, cocoa

I've been trying to understand this process, I've done a lot of reading and it's just not clicking so I would be grateful if anyone can break this down for me.

I have a method to retrieve JSON from a URL, parse it, and return the data via a completion handler. I could post code but it's all working and I (mostly) understand it.

In my completion handler I can print the data in the console so I know it's there and everything good so far.

The next bit is what's tripping me up. While I can use the data in the completion handler I can't access it from the view controller that contains the handler.

I want to be able to pass tableData.count to numberOfRows and get "Use of unresolved identifier 'tableData'"

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can lay out what I need to do next. Thanks!

Edit: adding code as requested

Here is my completion handler, defined in the ViewController class:

```
var tableData: [Patient] = []

var completionHandler: ([Patient]) -> Void = { (patients) in
print("Here are the \(patients)")
}
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://***.***.***.***/backend/returnA")
let returnA = URLRequest(url: url!)

retrieveJSON(with: returnA, completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

Defined in Networking.swift file:

```
func retrieveJSON(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping ([Patient]) -> Void) {

// set up the session
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

// make the request
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {

    // completion handler argument
    (data, response, error) in

    // completion handler
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Did not recieve data")
        completionHandler([])
        return
    }
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let Patient = try decoder.decode(Array<Patient>.self, from: data)
        // print(Patient)
        completionHandler(Patient)
    }
    catch let err {
        print("Err", err)
        completionHandler([])
    }
}
task.resume()

}
```

I also have a struct defined called Patient but I won't post that as it's very long and just a simple struct matching the JSON received.

Comment: Please post some code whatever you have tried.

Comment: I've edited my post, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you use closure, you should consider strong reference cycle.

```
let completionHandler: ([Patient]) -> Void = { [weak self] patients in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    strongSelf.tableData = patients // update tableData that must be used with UITableViewDataSource functions.
    strongSelf.tableView.reloadData() // notify tableView for updated data.
}
```

Comment: `strongSelf` is pretty *objective-c-ish*. In Swift there is *Optional Chaining*: `self?.tableData = patients`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That code gives me a "Use of unresolved identifier 'strongSelf'" error. using just "self" returns a "Value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> (ViewController)' has no member 'tableData'" error.

Comment: @rougement, your **completionHandler** must be in **same class with tableView**.

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating the array(tableData) in the closure:

```
var completionHandler: ([Patient]) -> Void = {[weak self] (patients) in
 print("Here are the \(patients)")
 self?.tableData = patients
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code gets "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value". Removing the "?" gives "Value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> (ViewController)' has no member 'tableData'".

Answer (score -1):

```
var tableData: [Patient] = []

var completionHandler: ([Patient]) -> Void = { (patients) in

self.tableData = patients
self.tableView.reloadData()
//make sure your tableview datasource has tableData property used 

}
```